# perfect modules over polynomial algebra

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, derived-categories

This may be obvious. My question is short:

$R$ is the polynomial algebra $\mathbb{k}[X_{1},\dots , X_{n}]$. Is the $R$-module $\mathbb{k}$ perfect in the sense that $\mathbb{k}$ is a compact object in the derived category $\mathbf{D}(R)$? You can consider $\mathbb{k}$ to be the field of rationals or complex numbers if it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The perfect objects in $\mathbf{D}(R)$ are the objects isomorphic to bounded complexes of finitely generated projective modules, and $\mathbb{k}$ is isomorphic in $\mathbf{D}(R)$ to its minimal projective resolution, which is such a complex.

More generally, in the derived category of a noetherian ring with finite global dimension, any finitely generated module is perfect.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a reference?